# CharacterSet to String and Int to Char casting

Tags: java, casting, char, int

New to java. Trying to familiarize myself with syntax and overall language structure.

I am trying to mimic this php function in java which just converts all instances of a number to a particular character

```
        for($x=10;$x<=20;$x++){
            $string = str_replace($x, chr($x+55), $string);
        }
```

so in php if a string was 1090412 it would be converted to something like A904C.

I am trying to do this in java by using string.replace but I cant for the life of me figure out how to cast the variables properly. I know that I can convert an integer to a character by casting it as (char), but not sure where to go from there. this gives me a compile error expecting a character set.

```
    string=1090412;
    for (x = 10; x <= 35; x++) {
        string.replace( x, (char) (x + 55));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although not the best way to do this, here is a method that works

```
import java.lang.*;

public class T {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1090412";
    for (int i = 10; i <= 20; i++) {
      s = s.replace(Integer.toString(i), "" + (char)(i + 55));
    }
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

The [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) object has a replace method on it. It is overloaded to take either two char parameters or two [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) objects. The `"" + (char)(i + 55)` is just a quick way to create a CharSequence.

Comment: why do you say that this is not the best way to do this?

Comment: well first off s.replace is going to search the entire string from start to beginning each time through the for loop.